# Binding to Linux System Event?

Tags: linux

for Linux, there is a nifty little library called xbindkeys that (surprise) binds commands of your choice to certain key combinations.

I am looking for something similar, except for a system hardware event. When I plug in my headphones to the output jack on my computer, I would like to be able to call a program. It would also be nice to be able to bind to the event when I un-plug my headphones.

Does anybody know if this is possible? Maybe through some cool Python X11 library?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Found the API for the jack abstraction layer: http://www.alsa-project.org/~tiwai/alsa-driver-api/ch06s02.html
Sadly, this only allows for polling of the device, not an event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `udev` for this. I haven't used libudev, but here's [something I found](http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/):

> **libudev - Monitoring Interface**
>
> libudev also provides a monitoring interface. The monitoring interface
>   will report events to the application when the status of a device
>   changes. This is useful for receiving notification when devices are
>   connected or disconnected from the system.

The actions are returned as the following strings:

> - add - Device is connected to the system
> - remove - Device is disconnected from the system
> - change - Something about the device changed
> - move - Device node was moved, renamed, or re-parented

That article goes on to show how it obtains a file descriptor via `udev_monitor_get_fd`, which it later monitors via `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern Linux desktops (notably Gnome and KDE) use "DBus".

DBus, in turn, utilizes HAL (older) and/or udev (newer).

Here are a couple of links that explain further:

https://www.linux.com/news/hardware/peripherals/180950-udev

http://w3.linux-magazine.com/issue/71/Dynamic_Device_Management_in%20Udev.pdf

http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html